# downloading zip files using R

Tags: r, rest, zip

I am trying to download a bunch of zip files from the website

https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/request/gis/watchwarn.phtml

Any suggestions? I have tried using rvest to identify the href, but have not had any luck.

Comment: which ZIPs do you need from that site? there are a few columns with different ones? you should also post the code that didn't work as an indicator that this is not a "please write this code for me" question.

Answer (score 1):

We can avoid platform-specific issues with `download.file()` and handle the downloads with `httr`.

First, we'll read in the page:

```
library(xml2)
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

pg <- read_html("https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/request/gis/watchwarn.phtml")
```

Now, we'll target all the `.zip` file links. They're relative paths (e.g. `<a href="/pickup/wwa/1986_all.zip">Zip</a>`) so we'll prepend the URL prefix to them as well:

```
html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//a[contains(@href, '.zip')]") %>% # this href gets _all_ of them
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  sprintf("https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu%s", .) -> zip_urls
```

Here's a sample of what ^^ looks like:

```
head(zip_urls)
## [1] "https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/data/gis/shape/4326/us/current_ww.zip"
## [2] "https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/pickup/wwa/1986_all.zip"              
## [3] "https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/pickup/wwa/1986_tsmf.zip"             
## [4] "https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/pickup/wwa/1987_all.zip"              
## [5] "https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/pickup/wwa/1987_tsmf.zip"             
## [6] "https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/pickup/wwa/1988_all.zip"
```

There are 84 of them:

```
length(zip_urls)
## [1] 84
```

So we'll *make sure* to include a `Sys.sleep(5)` in our download walker so we aren't hammering their servers since our needs are not more important than the site's.

Make a place to store things:

```
dir.create("mesonet-dl")
```

This could also be done with a `for` loop but using `purrr::walk` makes it fairly explicit we're generating side effects (i.e. downloading to disk and not modifying anything in the R environment):

```
walk(zip_urls, ~{

  message("Downloading: ", .x) # keep us informed

  # this is way better than download.file(). Read the httr man page on write_disk

  httr::GET(
    url = .x,
    httr::write_disk(file.path("mesonet-dl", basename(.x)))
  )

  Sys.sleep(5) # be kind

})
```

We use `file.path()` to construct the save-file location in a platform-agnostic way and use `basename()` to extract the filename portion vs regex hacking since it's an R C-backed internal function that is [platform-idiosyncrasy-aware](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/util.c#L788-L856).

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

setwd("YourDirectoryName") # set the directory where you want to download all files

read_html("https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/request/gis/watchwarn.phtml") %>%
  html_nodes(".table-striped a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  lapply(function(x) {
    filename <- str_extract(x, pattern = "(?<=wwa/).*") # this extracts the filename from the url
    paste0("https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu",x) %>% # this creates the relevant url from href
      download.file(destfile=filename, mode = "wb")
    Sys.sleep(5)})})
```

Comment: `download.file(..., mode = "wb")` is critical on Windows.

Comment: FWIW it's truly bad for to hammer a server with download requests without a delay.