# Download and unzip text files in R

Tags: r, download, unzip

I need to download the text files in R for Spain: https://economy-finance.ec.europa.eu/economic-research-and-databases/economic-databases/ameco-database/download-annual-data-set-macro-economic-database-ameco_en.

I was using the `fetchAmecoData` from the package `RGAP` but this function suddenly stopped working.

Comment: From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636557/downloading-zip-files-using-r) you can get a list off all zip urls and file names with `library(rvest); links = read_html(pth) %>% html_nodes(xpath=".//a[contains(@href, '.zip')]") ; filesNames = html_text(links) ; zipFiles = html_attr(links, "href")` (where `pth` is the url in your question. You can then either download all zip files or use the names to select whcih zip path t download.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
download.file("https://ec.europa.eu/economy_finance/db_indicators/ameco/documents/ameco0.zip",
          destfile = "~/R/so/temp.zip")
unzip("~/R/so/temp.zip", exdir = "~/R/so/")
```

Changing the directories as you need ('destfile' gives the target path you want to save the zip file to and that you then need in the unzip call, 'exdir' indicates the path where you want the files extracted to).

Comment: may want `mode = "wb"` in `download.file` if using windows